# Mahalanobis distance between two multivariate Gaussian distribution

Tags: distance, gaussian, mahalanobis

The Mahalanobis distance is a measure of the distance between a point P and a distribution D, can it be used to measure the distance of two MVG model?
how to deduce the function below?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxCae.png)

From wiki, the first term of Bhattacharyya distance is a squared Mahalanobis distance:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKqCz.png)
However, I don't know how to deduce that function.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read the how to ask. Add what you have tried so far and a sample of your data or an approximation